# Compilation error Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I am trying to learn how to create functions on Oracle. But I when I create my simple function it says that it was create but with compilation error.

This is my code:

```
create or replace function show_speed
  (in_nplate varchar2)
  return number
is
  ret number(4);
begin
  select speed into ret from cars where in_nplate = nplate;
  return ret;
end show_speed;
```

Now I what do this query,

```
select nplate, speed, show_speed(nplate) from cars;
```

It has to show all the plates of all cars and their speed 2 times, one for the attribute and second from the function.

I get this error:

> exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows. T

he error it show in the line: "select speed into...."

I was looking on internet but I don't find my mistake.

Comment: spelling of replace?

Comment: you misspelled REPLACE and you forget an ';' after declaring your variable 'ret'

Comment: also if you use a proper IDE like SQL Developer it will show you exactly where your errors are

Comment: Sorry I wrote wrong the code here but the 'replace' and ';' is in my run code. But it still no working

Comment: I have to use oracle and it doesn't says anything about your mistakes... :(

Comment: run this in sqlplus or whatever, and add a 'SHOW ERRORS' and then show us your errors

Comment: It says: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows. The error it show in the line: "select speed into...."

Comment: but now I don't know what I have changed but the function compiles  without errors

Comment: @DavidsZarzosoMoreno *I have to use Oracle* - sure, but use proper development tools with it, or at least research how to see the compilation errors using whatever tools you have. We don't get Java developers posting *My class compiled with an error, what could it be?* (Or do we?)

Comment: "exact fetch returns more than requested number of row" - you have a variable for a single object, a NUMBER. You are saying - go get everything FROM CARS where in_plate = nplate...and that's MORE THAN ONE THING. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html

Comment: To say again what Jeff Smith said already (but using different words): Your CARS table seems to have duplicates in the NPLATE column. So the SELECT returns two or three or more rows (at least for some values of NPLATE), and your function is supposed to capture "THE" speed (as in, the value from the one, single row returned by the SELECT). If your boss asked you to look on a list and fetch the speed for car with plate 'XYZ', and the list has three rows with plate 'XYZ' and different speeds, what would **you** do? You put Oracle exactly in that position!

Answer (score 0):

The error text

> exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows.

Told you that your table `cars` has two or more duplicates line.

For example:  imagin that you table contain the follow data.

```
car_____________speed_______in_plate    
toyota      |   70      |   plate_one     
shevrolette |   60      |   plate_two  
volvo       |   80      |   plate_two
```

when you execute your select without function it will return all lines, but in function you stick the result of select in one variable. And if select in fuction will return to you two lines then it will throw exception, because Oracle doesn't manage to stick two lines for one variable.

So, you have two different ways: throw throw exception from you function like that:

```
create or replace function show_speed
  (in_nplate varchar2)
  return number
is
  ret number(4);
begin
  select speed into ret from cars where in_nplate = nplate;
  return ret;
exception when too_many_rows than 
  return ret;  
end show_speed;
```

Or another way: process exception with `for .. loop`

```
create or replace function show_speed
  (in_nplate varchar2)
  return number
is
  ret varchar(4);
begin
  for x in (select speed from cars where in_nplate = nplate)
loop
      ret:= ret||','||x.speed;
end loop;
      return ret;  
end show_speed;
```

but this varians is not compatible with your expectings.